# How can I improve this ridge regression?

Tags: r

the result of R-squared of the ridge regression is worst than the linear. How can it get better? I am doing linear and ridge regression in order to predict the variable quality (range 1 to 10) in a wineQuality dataset. Then, after the ridge I have to perform KNN with 10 different K's.

```
#train and test
train[c(12)] <-lapply(train[c(12)], function(x){(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))})
test[c(12)] <-lapply(test[c(12)], function(x){(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))})

head(train)

#linear regression
m1 <- lm(I(quality) ~ ., data = train)
mtable(m1)

#ridge regression
y <- train$quality
x <- data.matrix(train[, c("fixed.acidity","volatile.acidity", "citric.acid", "residual.sugar", "chlorides", "free.sulfur.dioxide", "total.sulfur.dioxide", "density", "pH", "sulphates")])

#setting range of lambda
lambda_seq <- 10^seq(2, -2, by = -.1)


#fitting the model

fit <- glmnet(x, y, alpha = 0, lambda = lambda_seq)

#checking the model
summary(fit)


#choosing optimal lambda

ridge_cv <- cv.glmnet(x, y, alpha = 0, lambda = lambdas)

# Best lambda value
best_lambda <- ridge_cv$lambda.min
best_lambda

#k-cross validation for best fit

best_fit <- ridge_cv$glmnet.fit
head(best_fit)


#best ridge with optimal lambda 

best_ridge <- glmnet(x, y, alpha = 0, lambda = 0.001)

#R2 values for train and test

eval_results <- function(true, predicted, df) {
  SSE <- sum((predicted - true)^2)
  SST <- sum((true - mean(true))^2)
  R_square <- 1 - SSE / SST
  RMSE = sqrt(SSE/nrow(df))

  
# Model performance metrics
data.frame(
  RMSE = RMSE,
  Rsquare = R_square
)
  
}

#predictions on train 

predictions_train <- predict(best_ridge, s = best_lambda, newx = x)
eval_results(y, predictions_train, train)
```

The result of the R-squared of the linear is 0.286 and the one of the ridge is 0.2825005. Are there any errors in the code? how can I improve it?

Comment: Without reproducible data set, it's difficult to know.

Comment: This might be more appropriate for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions), which is a dedicated statistics Stack Exchange. Also please provide the dataset, which can be found at [UCI's ML datasets repo](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/wine+quality)